# Firestore Collection (with Subcollection) to Sqflite Item in Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, sqflite

My application is using firestore database. I design *categories and its subcategories* of the content by using subcollection.

To make offline mode feature; 
I want to save this firestore data to sqflite database.

I learned that I convert firebase data map to text for sqlite

But I counl't find a way to locate the **subcollections**.

```
 var catagorySnapshots =
        await _firestore.collection("categories").getDocuments();
    List _list = [];
    catagorySnapshots.documents.forEach((_snapshot) {
      CategoryInformation categoryInformation = CategoryInformation();
      CategoryItem curCategory =
          CategoryItem.fromCollection(_snapshot.documentID, _snapshot.data);
      categoryInformation.categoryList.add(curCategory);
      print(curCategory.title);
      //
      // sub collections
      //
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? @Levent KANTAROGLU

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to answer, this might help someone else.
You have to try getting the information from snapshot.data['field'] like so and covert it to text as well.

Let me know of that works.